# primeng p-dropdown not firing onShow, onHide event

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I am using primeng version 6.1.0 in my angular app version 6. I am facing an issue where i want to trigger an event on closing p-dropdown, not by selecting any item but by clicking outside the p-dropdown list. I have already used click event so, I want another work around to fire and event upon closing of primeng dropdown.

I have tried onHide event  by primeng p-dropdown documentation

in html:

```
<p-dropdown (click)="clickToDisable()" [options]="activeCustomerStatus" [(ngModel)]="selectedFilterStatus" optionLabel="label" 
 (onHide)="enableButton($event)"></p-dropdown>
```

in component:

```
enableButton($event) {
console.log('onHideWorks');
}
```

Output: By using onHide, that console message should be displayed on console.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see (cause I could not find the 6.1.0 docs for dropdown), at version 6.1.0 
the `onHide` event emitter wasn't available

[GitHub/PrimeNg/Dropdown](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/6.1.0/src/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts)